# How can I print all the elements in a Generic Linked List Queue?

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, queue

This is the current method I'm working with. `newt` is the name of the Generic `LinkedList` `Queue`.

`newt.peek()` returns the data inside of the *head* of the *queue*.

I'm not sure how to go through each element in the queue (this is my first time working with a queue) and print the data in each one.

```
//Print all elements of the queue.
public void printProcessQueue() {
    boolean hasMore = true;
    while (hasMore) {
        if (newt.peek() != null) {
            System.out.println(newt.head);
            //Cannot figure out how to get the next in queue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is queue in your question? FIFO implementation with peek/poll/offer methods only or collection?

Comment: it is FIFO collection. I have the peek method, but I'm not familiar with poll/offer

Comment: If it is your custom implementation of the `LinkedList` data structure, then share the rest of the code related to the problem. But it's a `Collection` (i.e. `LinkedList` from the JDK) what means `newt.head`?

Answer (score 2):

> how to go through each element in the queue and print the data in each one

You can do it by removing the *head* of the *queue* in a loop until the *queue* is not empty:

```
public void printQueue() {
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {              // basically you can use `queue.peek() != null`, but `isEmpty()` is more preferable because it's more expressive
        System.out.println(queue.remove()); // or queue.poll()
    }
}
```

If you're not OK with removing all the elements from the *queue*, then you can make use of the *iterator*. But **note** that *iterator* created over the elements of the *queue* will not necessarily guarantee to traverse them in any specific order. It will depend on the implementation: for instance, `ArrayDeque` and `LinkedList` give you such guarantee, but `PriorityQueue` doesn't.

```
public void printQueue() {
    Iterator<MyType> iterator = queue.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

*Sidenote:* when you need a `Queue` (or `Deque`) favor `ArrayDeque` over `LinkedList` as a more performant implementation.